# How to extract Panels from a comic book image using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, imagemagick, image-manipulation

Heres the image

[image]

As you can see there are 6 panels in this particular image, however I would like to generalize this to all comic book page images. I am trying to extract these panels into 6 separate images.

The first thing I have tried is OpenCV's findCountours.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('sample-chapter/one-piece-1693192.jpg')
imgrey = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(imgrey,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

contours,heirarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh1,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(img,contours,-1,(0,255,0),3)
cv2.imwrite('threshold_image.png',thresh1)
```

As you can see I have used RETR_EXTERNAL which I am told gives only the extreme outer contours - the parent of all child contours. However, this still doesn't give the panels - but the contours of the images inside:

[image]

Now I am wondering if some kind of contiguous area selection and removal (starting from say (0,0) at the upper left) might help - Perhaps something will permit me to segment the image every time it runs into a transparent pixel? Im really not sure where to go from here. Any advice?

Comment: Looks like a poor scan, with some of the edges missing, which makes it harder, since now some of the frames are not actually framed. Maybe reduce the contours into convex hulls as a start?

Comment: Something like [this](http://pastebin.com/bMeKnm76) seems to get you a step further... Still has an issue with that cropped bottom-left frame tho.

Comment: @DanMašek wow thats great. Sure its a little messy but I bet I could throw away all contours smaller than a certain size and accomplish the jist of what I'm trying to do... Could you perhaps add it as an answer an explain what you are doing, especially why you are finding the contours twice?

Comment: I am kind of surprised that some of the big black edges of the cases are missed... You could try to apply a Canny filter by yourself (so you can play with the thresholds) and then apply a Hough transform keeping only the longest lines found. And then use some kind of home-made rule to check for parallel lines (as contiguous cases share parallel lines apparently).

Comment: Check the `skimage` library (`scikit-image`) too. I find it way easier to use than openCV with Python when working with contours... (this is a personal opinion)

Comment: The edge detector seems to only filter vertical edges. Maybe try to use your own Sobel Filter in both directions (horizontal and vertical).